# RoR asset pipeline best practices for one-off JS plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a best practices question regarding one-off javascript plugins and their role in the Rails asset pipeline.

I'm new to Rails, and am working on a new project. The site template I'm using uses a large collection of js plugins for added functionality. (eq chartjs.org, ckeditor, and about 40 others) Since these are needed on a page-by-page basis, I'm not sure if I should really load them all in the application.js manifest.

Currently, I have the template's assets under the /vendor directory and only the core assets are being loaded from my application.js manifest.

Thoughts on how/where to include the plugins?

Answer (score 0):

As i know that rails default added all js file include in application.js by //= require_tree . so, you can remove it and add only those file which you want to added. and if you want to run only specific function then you can use location.pathname with condition and it will work for only that specific page.